# Qt and Qt Creator. Pure installation

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I used Qt Creator 3.5.0 without any problems. But after these actions I got some issues:

1. I always used Qt Creator without super permissions, but at that time I launched it as `root`
2. After that I tried to run Qt Creator as usually but got a lot of errors like:

> Cannot overwrite file
>   /home/user/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/qtversion.xml: Permission
>   denied
>
> Could not save session to file
>   /home/user/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/default.qws
>
> Cannot overwrite file
>   /home/user/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/qnx/qnxconfigurations.xml:
>   Permission denied

3. My Android emulator settings has been reset.
4. I also got some messages like:

> No .user settings file created by this instance of Qt Creator was
>   found...

5. I could not save some files due to:

> Cannot set permissions for /home/user/QtProjects/test_project/mainwindow.cpp to writable.
>   Could not save the files.

6. > /home/user/QtProjects/build-test_project-Desktop-Debug/ui_mainwindow.h:13:
   >   error: QtWidgets/QAction: No such file or directory
7. But the main problem is that I can't use some my packages which are already installed:

> No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
>
> No package 'gstreamer-1.0' found
>
> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Some of these errors occurs with `sudo`, some - without.

I already tried to completely reinstall Qt, Qt Creator(using `apt-get` and online installer) and missing packages and I also removed dir `QtProject` and file `QtProject.conf` from `/home/user/.config`, but without success.

**So how can I absolutely clean and purge Qt, its configs and settings and make pure reinstallation to solve these problems?**

Comment: Check if /home/user/.config it self is owned by root. Nuke the build dir and change the permissions in the source folder to your user.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld problems with permissions are solved, but I still can't use packages which I used before.

Comment: What do you mean with "packages"?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld item #7 in the my question.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change qt versions in the process? QtWebkit is deprecated and not part of the prebuilt Qt packages anymore, since Qt 5.6. So if you changed the Qt version from <= 5.5 to 5.6, this is expected.

Answer (score 2):

To answer #2, #4, and #5 - these all stem from file ownership being by the 'root' user, caused by when you launched Qt Creator as root.

To fix these issues:

```
$ chown user:user -R /home/user/.config/QtProject/qtcreator
$ chown user:user -R /home/user/QtProjects
$ rm -Rf /home/user/QtProjects/build-test_project-Desktop-Debug
```

The first two directives makes sure that all the Qt projects you have in QtProjects and all Qt Creator user settings files are owned by the user, so it can be accessed by the Qt Creator project when launched by the user.

The last directive removes your build files, which will be regenerated when you next build - in case they are in an inconsistent state due to the permissions being wrong.

As to #7 - as what Frank Osterfeld mentioned, you have enabled Qt Webkit support in your project, and it's been removed from Qt as of Qt 5.6*. I would recommend replacing your usage of Qt Webkit with Qt WebEngine.

<sub>* https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6#Removed_Modules</sub>